# How do you make a vector that displays 24,60, and 1?

Tags: c++, vector

Simple problem that I know I should know.  All I want to do is display a vector when I give it those parameters, then I have to display it in reverse order.

Comment: What do you mean by _display_ a vector? On the console?

Comment: I want to output those numbers yes.

Comment: You're looking for `std::cout` then. Google it, and find out the rest yourself - there are many examples out there!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector) first. 
The following code compiles in C++98.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> myvec;
    myvec.push_back(1); myvec.push_back(2); myvec.push_back(3);
    for( vector<int>::iterator it = myvec.begin(); it!=myvec.end(); ++it){
        cout<<*it<<"  ";
    }    
    cout<<"\nRverse Order "<<endl;
    for( vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = myvec.rbegin(); it!=myvec.rend(); ++it){
        cout<<*it<<"  ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this

1. Using loops and indices and printing to the screen.
2. Using iterators.

However, as you realize that in both cases you're outputting to the screen, it may be a better idea to use a stream to encapsulate this behavior by using an overloaded insertion operator (in addition to one of those paradigms):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const vector<int>& v) {
    for (std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it) {
        out << *it << " ";//you can use a newline here if you wanted every element on a new line
    }
    return out;
}
```

Usage:

```
vector<int> vec;
//fill `vec` with data
//...
std::cout << vec << std::endl;
```

**WARNING**

*While this is a sensible idea as it is arguably more object-oriented, it abstracts away the meaning of the extraction operator as it violates the principle of [least surprise](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment). However, if this behavior is intended and consistent, then depending on your usage, it is perfectly fine.*